# pseudo selection nth-child tweeking

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've checked several blogs and I cannot find the answer to my problem. Maybe you can.

In the first `ul` (With class `.first`) there has to be a different background applied to each `li`. So I wanted to use pseudo elements to learn how to use them. I changed the number of the selector for each `li` element. I had to use `:after` so I could move the image background with position `absolute`. I used this CSS:

```
> ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover:after
> ul li:nth-child(2) a:hover:after
etc
```

To make this even more tricky the second `ul` (class .dropdown) needs to have a different background than the `li` in `ul.first`. But all the `li` will have the same background in `ul.dropdown`. I simply added a background and there began the problem, I get the background of `ul.first`. I would like the CSS to only target the `li` of `ul.first`, so I can separately target `ul.dropdown`

This is the html:

```
<nav>
    <a href="index.html">
        <h1 class="sprites-logo- ir">cepods</h1>
    </a>
    <ul class="first">
        <li>
            <a href="#">about</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">how we work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropli">
            <a href="#">design<i class="icon-right-open"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">restaurant</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">retail</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">event space</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">bar</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">living</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">hotel</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
             <a href="#">news</a>
        </li>
        <li>
             <a href="#">faq</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector starts with:

```
ul li
```

Which selects *all* li's inside the ul. Since the li's in the "dropdown" are also inside the "first" ul, they get targeted too with your rule.

To select only the li's that are directly inside the first one, you can use

```
ul > li
```

Which only selects li's that are a direct child of the ul.

However, "dropdown" is also an ul, so this rule would still apply to both. Instead, target the first ul directly, and then target it's children directly:

```
.first > li:nth-child(1) a:hover:after
etc..
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is the code I have at this moment: nav .first > li:nth-child(3) a:hover, nav .first > li:nth-child(3) a:active. The problem is that it's still affecting the hover status of the links inside the second ul (.dropdown). I do not understand why that is? Am I doing something more complicated than it should be?

Comment: Hello Stephan. Hereby I've added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DqFLe/. I tried to load the background images via dropbox but doesn;t seem to work. I inserted my whole CSS, the interesting part for you would be from line 1105. Thank you very much!

Comment: Holy smokes batman. If you need 600 lines of css for a simple dropdown menu you're doing something wrong. Let me see if I can clean that up for you a bit before I even start debugging.

Comment: Some random comments while cleaning: transform has a shorthand property: `transform: rotate 0.15s ease-in`. You don't have to repeat the individual properties, saving you already dozens of lines of code. Also, you're not familiar with inheritance/cascading apparently. `nav .main a:first-child:before` and `nav .main a:before` have the exact same styles, but since `a:first-child:before` already is a subset of all `a:before`s, you don't need that first entire rule. If anything in first-child needs to be _different_ than in the other ones, all you need is to state those different properties.

Comment: Also, you repeat the exact same styles dozens of times. Instead of repeating `nav .main > li:nth-child(x) a:link` many times updating the x, why not just use `nav .main > li a:link`? Then for those nth-childs that _are_ different, just add the properties that _differ_ from the rest.

Comment: Honestly, this list goes on. I'm afraid I'm not going to be able to debug a 600 line stylesheet. Learn the basics of CSS (especially the "C": Cascading). Trim it down to ~100 lines and maybe I or someone else can take a look at it for you.

Comment: Here, I trimmed about 350 lines and that's even with a lot of comments for you to explain what I did. http://jsfiddle.net/DqFLe/4/ I didn't even look at what the effects were on the output, I think this code could be optimized a lot more but this is just for you to learn from.